# android go back button

Tags: android

I want to build a "quotes app" so every time the user clicks on the button a random quote appears. But I also want to set an button, which takes the user back to the quote he saw before. And because it always picks a quote randomly I wanted to store the int number of the quote, so every time someone clicks the button it stores in a int string which quote has been shown. But I get errors all the time. can someone give me an sample code for such a back-button? thanks (button2 should be bak button)

final int[] Random2 = {};

```
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Zufallszahl1 = Würfel.nextInt(98);

             Random2[counter] = Zufallszahl1;
            counter++;


                text1.setText(Lines[Zufallszahl1]

            );

        }

    });


    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            text1.setText(Lines[Random2[counter-1]]);
        }
    });



}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this ;

1. Store the history in an array, and override the "back button" to go back through this
2. Use the android native backstack.

As a first attempt id always go with number 2.

Think about it this way,

Your activity shows a random quote
Pressing the "Next" button starts another "random quote" activity.

In this way android keeps the backstack for you!

You just need to fire an intent for your RandomQuoteActivity.

Answer (score 0):

You **should** give us the error of the logcat. Your error is probably an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, because your Array Random2 is empty. If you want an array that can grow as you add items in it, use a Vector

```
final Vector<Integer> Random2 = new Vector<Integer>();

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Zufallszahl1 = Würfel.nextInt(98);

         Random2.add(Zufallszahl1);
        //We don't need a counter, Vector already has one

            text1.setText(Lines[Zufallszahl1]

        );

    }

});


button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        text1.setText(Lines[Random2.get(Random2.size()-1)]);
        //you should also remove the last quote off the vector's stack with something like Random2.remove(Random2.size()-1);
    }
});
```

Comment: ok i understand but my eclipse says: vector couldnt be resolved to a typ

Comment: Did you import java.util.Vector ? Do you type "Vector" and not "vector" ?